# How to filter custom words if they have symbols to bypass filter

Tags: python, filter, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord bot that filters bad words
(In korean)
I tried making one but everone did bypass by adding special characters besides them if cat it's bad word they say ca!t to bypass filter
how can I stop this?

I have tried profanity filter but i had no luck with korean characters

```
    Badwords=["cat","dog"]
    replacement="***"
    #message.content it's the string!
    for s in Badwords:
            if (s in str(message.content)):
                if (config['SETTINGS']['MODE']=="REPLACE"):
                    fixed=str(message.content)
                    for bad in Badwords:
                        fixed=fixed.replace(bad, replacement)
                    await message.channel.send(message.author.name+":"+fixed)
                    await message.delete()
                else:
                    await message.delete()
                return
```

if you type cat it will filter and replace with *** or defending on settings it should delete the message this works but if you type ca!t or ca@t it will bypass the filter how do i stop this?

Comment: how it should react on `c--at` or `(c)at` ? (it's too broad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help to use the for loop for each space you get in between two strings in your message. right now you are checking each bad word you have in the list, with each word in message which is very weird and bad way to do it.

I suggest you make a list of special characters and filter those out first, then compare the remaining strings in message separated by white spaces with BadWords list and if any word is found you can replace it with stars. 
if you wish to get back the special characters you removed, it will be a very complex code. I would keep it as lightweight as possible.

Comment: actully the solution was create a list with every special character and bad word so list should be cat !cat c!at ca!t cat!

Comment: Glad you found it! Seems like a brute-force approach to it but if it works then it works! Anyways thanks for replying back.